# How do you add title and meta description on a DjangoCMS template?

Tags: python, django, django-cms

i'm working with djangoCMS and i have created all the templates and they are working fine, now my issue is on the djangoCMS page creation fields i fill a couple of fields, the page name, slug, menu title and page title. How do i add and display meta descriptions on my pages?

Comment: Did you check this out? https://djangocms-page-meta.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and I managed to solve by the below code in my base template

```
{% page_attribute "meta_description" %}
```